# How to debug a value from a function if it is called inside return statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want to know how to get the value from a function if it is inside a returning statement.
For instance, I have the following function;

```
function a () {
    return b(); // How to know the value returning from b() if I put the debuger in this line??
}
```

If I put a debugger in the return statement, It enters that line, but when I press F10, it already returns and I can't see the value displayed. How do I get this value before changing the page?

As a work around, what I'm doing currently is creating an additional line before returning:

```
const result = b(); return result;
```

But, this is a work around and it's hard to do it everything, because there are thousands of lines like this in the code, and everytime I need to change back to the previous state before submitting the code to production, otherwise it's not accepted.

Comment: Maybe you can do instead `const result = b(); return result;` like in 2 lines, so you will see in the variable called `result`.

Comment: Yes, I know this, but this is a workaround. I will have to change the code back to the previous state before sending to production, otherwise it won't pass the review.

Comment: I suspect you cannot, because that's a single statement. You need a workaround like a temp variable (what you're doing) or maybe a watch expression (though I guess that would execute the function twice).

Answer (score 0):

You need to step into the b() function, F11

Comment: Alright, but what if that function that I'm pressing F11 is also returning a function? And the one after that, and so on, when it eventually enters a node_module and it goes on and on forever.

Comment: once it breaks on "return b()", set breakpoint on a line inside b() and hit continue.

Comment: or you can just highlight b() and select Evaluate if you want to know what b() would return

Comment: What I meant is that function b() can have an return c() as his return statament, then I would need to press F11 inside in it aswell

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods to return values from a function which are pointers,structures and array.
In this you have to do execute a function and return a value to the calling function.